# What is `External exception A0` and what is the root cause?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

On my mobile app, under android, build with Delphi Rio in 64 bit, I have often some exceptions named "External exception XX" like for example :

```
External exception 90  
External exception 87  
External exception A0
etc...
```

and this a little everywhere in the code, even at very usual place like :

```
Fmx.Types.ArrangeControl(Fmx.Types.IAlignableObject, Fmx.Types.TAlignLayout, Single, Single, Single, Single, var Types.TRectF)
```

or

```
TRectF.Offset(Double, Double)
```

but also in other places. **I can not reproduce this problem locally**, I receive this error log from client devices and **it's on every devices not only on a specific one**.

for example this is the call stack of one of the report I receive:

```
External exception B0
At address: $0000007FFE2E2270

Call stack:
libmyapp.so $000000726EE8F618 Grijjy.Errorreporting.TgoExceptionReporter.GlobalGetExceptionStackInfo(TExceptionRecord*) + 128
libmyapp.so $000000726E61D5E0 Sysutils.Exception.RaisingException(TExceptionRecord*) + 52
libmyapp.so $000000726E647BD4 Sysutils.RaiseExceptObject(TExceptionRecord*) + 64
libmyapp.so $000000726E5FDB60 _RaiseAtExcept(TObject*, Pointer) + 100
libmyapp.so $000000726E61C6AC Internal.Excutils.SignalConverter(NativeUInt, NativeUInt, NativeUInt) + 56
libmyapp.so $000000726EC63E80 Fmx.Types.ArrangeControl(Fmx.Types.IAlignableObject, Fmx.Types.TAlignLayout, Single, Single, Single, Single, var Types.TRectF) + 112
libmyapp.so $000000726EC646BC Fmx.Types.AlignObjects(Fmx.Types.TFmxObject*, Fmx.Types.TBounds*, Single, Single, var Single, var Single, var Boolean).DoAlign(Pointer, Fmx.Types.TAlignLayout) + 556
libmyapp.so $000000726EC64954 Fmx.Types.AlignObjects(Fmx.Types.TFmxObject*, Fmx.Types.TBounds*, Single, Single, var Single, var Single, var Boolean) + 508
libmyapp.so $000000726ECD7AF8 Fmx.Forms.TCustomForm.Realign() + 168
libmyapp.so $000000726ECD391C Fmx.Forms.TCommonCustomForm.Updated() + 36
libmyapp.so $000000726ECD3868 Fmx.Forms.TCommonCustomForm.EndUpdate() + 252
libmyapp.so $000000726ECD892C Fmx.Forms.TCustomForm.EndUpdate() + 20
libmyapp.so $000000726F078090 main.TMainForm.ShowFrame(baseframe.TMainBaseFrame*, Boolean, definition.TShowFrameTransition) + 3304
libmyapp.so $000000726F078A2C main.TMainForm.ShowPreviousFrame() + 1820
libmyapp.so $000000726F0717E4 main.TMainForm.FormKeyUp(TObject*, var Word, var Char, set of Classes.System_Classes__1) + 452
libmyapp.so $000000726ECD2D0C Fmx.Forms.TCommonCustomForm.KeyUp(var Word, var Char, set of Classes.System_Classes__1) + 104
libmyapp.so $000000726EC15978 Fmx.Platform.Ui.Android.TAndroidTextInputManager.KeyUp(var Word, var Char, set of Classes.System_Classes__1, Boolean) + 72
libmyapp.so $000000726EC114B0 Fmx.Platform.Ui.Android.TAndroidTextInputManager.HandleAndroidKeyEvent(AInputEvent*) + 976
libmyapp.so $000000726EC39204 Fmx.Platform.Android.TPlatformAndroid.HandleAndroidInputEvent(Androidapi.Appglue.TAndroidApplicationGlue*, AInputEvent*) + 64
libmyapp.so $000000726E8F723C Androidapi.Appglue.TAndroidApplicationGlue.InputEventHandler(Integer, Integer, Pointer) + 184
libutils.so $0000007312C962D0 android::Looper::pollInner(int) + 936
libutils.so $0000007312C95E90 android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**) + 64
$0000007310BF4A80
```

What can cause this error and how can I found the root cause?

Comment: If these exceptions appear to be occurring at random places then my first suggestion would be for you to enable range checking. It is possible that you may be accessing some memory out of bonds which is then causing memory corruption and could thus lead to numerous unpredictable and untraceable exceptions.

Comment: @SilverWarior yes, but in debug I m always with range checking ON. I will set it to on in release also but I doubt a little that is this but who know, the advice is quite good !